# C# web service convert string to DateTime and insert into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Been trying to insert a date, along with some other string data, into SQL via C#, as such:

```
OperationResponse ICommon.addUser(userRequest request)
    {
        int? result = 0;
        Guid countryGUID;

        string requestParent = request.parent;
        string requestName = request.name;
        string requestSchool = request.school;
        int requestGender = request.gender;
        DateTime dateTimeDOB = DateTime.ParseExact(request.DOB, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string requestEmail = request.email;
        string requestMobile = request.mobile;
        Guid.TryParse(request.countryID, out countryGUID);
        string requestInstitution = request.institution;

        try
        {
            result = s2u.AddUser(request.parent, request.name, request.school, request.gender, dateTimeDOB, request.email, request.mobile, countryGUID, request.institution);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            if (isDebug() == true)
            {
                return new OperationResponse(ex.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                return new OperationResponse("Error: Database inaccessible.");
            }
        }

        if (result == 1)
        {
            return new OperationResponse();
        }
        else
        {
            return new OperationResponse("Error: User could not be added.");
        }
    }
```

However whenever I try to run it in Fiddler it's been unsuccessful thus far, since the result always ends up being -1.

I suspect this may have something to do with the DOB not being inserted correctly, but I can't be sure. The request.DOB that I'm trying to parse is a string, the DOB column in the SQL table has the date datatype, and I'm trying to pass in dates in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd", but on the C# side I have to pass in the time too, being 12.00.00 AM by default. I don't know if this is causing problems. Any help is appreciated, and I'll provide further details if needed.

EDIT: The AddUser stored procedure is as such:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @parent nvarchar(300),
    @name nvarchar(300),
    @school nvarchar(500),
    @gender int,
    @DOB datetime2(7),
    @email nvarchar(500),
    @mobile nvarchar(20),
    @countryID uniqueidentifier,
    @institution nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([parent], [name], [school], [gender], [DOB], [email], [mobile], [countryID], [institution])
    VALUES (@parent, @name, @school, @gender, @DOB, @email, @mobile, @countryID, @institution);
END
```

Comment: If the `ParseExact` call works then there's no issue with converting the `String` to a `DateTime` and the issue must be inside `s2u.AddUser`.  As you've given us no information about how that method works there's exactly zero chance of our diagnosing the issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Apologies, I have added information about the AddUser stored procedure.

Comment: What exactly is `s2u`?

Comment: At this stage you would normally go through the web service error logs to find the error. Don't have any? Add them in then next interation! Failing that the next step is to reproduce the error in a DEV environment then use the debugger in C# to work out what line it's failing on. Can't do that? The next thing I would do is use SQL Profiler to work out what is being called against the database and what isn't - that gives you some idea of where your code is getting to.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry I left that out, that's comes from my Entity Framework. I declared this above the addUser method: `Scholarship2UEntities s2u = new Scholarship2UEntities();`

Comment: The stored procedure is helpful, but what he was really asking for was the `Scholarship2UEntities.AddUser()` method.

Comment: It looks like if you turn debug on you might get a useful exception message returned. I suggest you try that to get a more useful response than -1

Comment: I would recommend you to make `request.DOB` a `DateTime`. Why would your service consume a datetime as a string in an unknown format, when you can simply consume DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

Check your string date time is in correct format or not. I believe it's not in correct format.

Moreover, why didn't you use the following method?

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
```

With EF, datetime is mostly handle as a datetime2 type, so it won't make much difference or cause any trouble.

In addition, write transaction handles in stored procedure with try & catch and try to find out if sp is giving any problems or not.